# using @viewChild in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have an application that use @ViewChild and below is the code I have

```
 @ViewChild('paginator', { read: MatPaginator, static: true}) public paginator: MatPaginator;
```

on the front I am using
`<mat-paginator [ngStyle]="{'display': orders.length > 0 ? 'flex': 'none' }" #paginator>` 
and I have implemented AfterViewInit and this is the code I have just to check that the paginator has been initialised:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('tab group', this.paginator);
}
```

but the this.tabGroup is undefined and hence I can't set it's property. What am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You've shown us the code where `this.paginator` is declared. Where do you declare `this.tabGroup`?

Comment: sorry was supposed to be this.paginator. it's a typo as I have two on the same page LOL. I ahve changed the code now

Comment: Does your template have any `*ngIf` in DOM elements around the paginator?

Comment: it is straight after a DIV with an if so I have <div class="table-wrapper" *ngIf="orders?.length > 0"> gjhgjhgjhgjh</div> <mat-paginator [ngStyle]="{'display': orders.length > 0 ? 'flex': 'none' }" #paginator>

Comment: Have you tried using `{ static: false }` ?

Comment: yup same result

Comment: @heunetik you are right adding { static: false } is the answer, If you want you can write it in the answer section and I will mark it. cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Angular 8 `ViewChild` and `ContentChild` decorators must have a new option called static.

If you add `static: true` on a dynamic element (wrapped in a condition or a loop), then it will not be accessible in `ngOnInit` nor in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Setting it to `static: false` should behave as you're expecting it to.

Also, when updating to Angular 8, in the command line there will be a message explaining the new `ViewChild` and `ContentChild` changes, and a link [this documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration), and [here's the pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810) of the changes, with some explanations. This might help wrapping your head around the changes.